# C: Passing by Reference between Multiple Functions?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to pass by reference (or rather, by pointer) between multiple functions. I understand the basics of pass by reference, and have successfully managed that for individual functions. I cannot seem to understand how to pass one variable by reference along multiple functions.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int* quicksort(int*, int, int, long long int*);
    int *sortedList = malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof(int));
    long long int compCount=0; 
    sortedList = quicksort(LIST, 0, MAX_LENGTH-1, &compCount); 
    printf("%lld", compCount);
    return 0;
}

int* quicksort(int* A, int l, int r, long long int* compCount) { 
    int partition(int*, int, int, long long int*);
    int p;
    if (!(l < r)) { 
        return A;
    }
    else { 
        p = partition(A, l, r, compCount); 
        quicksort(A, l, p-1, compCount);
        quicksort(A, p+1, r, compCount); 
    }
    return A;
}

int partition(int *A, int l, int r, long long int* compCount) {
    int i, j, p, tmp; 
    i = l + 1;
    p = l; 

    for (j = l + 1; j <= r; j++) {
        if (A[j] < A[p]) {
            tmp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = tmp;
            i = i+1; 
        }
    }
    compCount += r-l; 
    tmp = A[l];
    A[l] = A[i-1];
    A[i-1] = A[l];
    return i-1; 
}
```

I get a value of compCount = 0 at the end of this. I know I can solve this issue by using a global variable, but I'd rather not use a global.

How am I mis-using my pointers?

Comment: `compCount += r-l;` should be `*compCount += r-l; `

Comment: `sortedList = quicksort(LIST, 0, MAX_LENGTH-1, &compCount);` probably memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the pointers correctly between the functions. The problem is that you're then updating the pointer instead of what it's pointing to.

```
compCount += r-l;
```

should be:

```
*compCount += r-l;
```

Unrelated to this issue, the sort is done in-place, so `sortedList` will be assigned the same pointer as the original list, and your `malloc` is unneeded and will be leaked.

Comment: You should see a compiler warning about this, something like 'assigning integer to pointer type (default allowed)". In general, you should shoot for writing warning free code.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Adding an integer to a pointer is a valid and common operation. There is no reason for a warning.

Comment: You're right, its probably more like `assigning an integral type to a pointer`. I've edited my comment. I know for a fact gcc supplies something akin to this.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Assigning an integer to a pointer would cause a warning. But adding an integer to a pointer (which was done here) will not.

Comment: @midor The leak is the unnecessary `malloc` in `main` which then gets overwritten by another value.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the result of `quicksort` (an `int *`) is useless. The signature is confusing: one could believe that `quicksort` accepts an array `A` and returns a sorted copy of `A` (`A` not being modified). Clearly `A` is modified in-place. So what is the interest of returning `A` ? Let's remark that the 2 recursive calls to `quicksort` simply ignore the returned values. This returned value is useless. BTW what is `LIST` in the main (not declared) ? Should not it be SortedList instead ?

This signature of your function should be:

```
 void quicksort(int* A, int l, int r, long long int* compCount);
```

You can now use the return value to return the number of comparisons (btw a `long` is enough):

```
long quicksort(int* A, int l, int r) { 
    int partition(int*, int, int, long*);
    int p;
    if (!(l < r)) { 
        return 0;
    } else {
        long compCount = 0;
        p = partition(A, l, r, &compCount); 
        compCount += quicksort(A, l, p-1);
        compCount += quicksort(A, p+1, r); 
    }

    return compCount;
}
```

Additional remark: `partition` can be simplified since it now always receives `compCount = 0` thus:

```
*compCount += r-l;
```

becomes

```
*compCount = r-l;
```

and thus, there is no longer need to initialize `compCount` in `quicksort`:

```
long quicksort(int* A, int l, int r) { 
    int partition(int*, int, int, long*);
    int p;
    long compCount;

    if (!(l < r)) { 
        return 0;
    }

    p = partition(A, l, r, &compCount); 
    return compCount + quicksort(A, l, p-1) + quicksort(A, p+1, r); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you call as reference, you are actually passing pointer by value. When you pass a pointer, the content of the pointer can be changed by dereferencing, so you should do:

```
*compCount += r-l;
```